# How to add a Groundoverlay with gmap4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

With gmap4rails I created a map with some markers in my railsapplication. Now I want to add a groundOverlay of a custom made map over this map that I created. I found some documentation in the Google MAPS API(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays), but I cannot figure out the right syntax to do this with gmap4rails. Does anyone now how to do this?

My code so far:

```
    <% content_for(:after_js) do %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>

  var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.346415, 4.853680),
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.402162, 4.978654)
    );

  $(document).on('ready', function(){
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({
    internal: {id: 'map'},
    provider: {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.373095,4.8909129,17),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      draggable: true,
      styles:    mapStyle
     }
    },
    function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @markers.to_json %>);
                handler.bounds.extendWidth(markers);
                handler.fitMapToBounds();

    });
  })
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I want to add something like this:

```
groundoverlay: {
            options: {
                url: "custommap.jpg",
                bounds: {
                    sw: {
                        lat: 52.346415,
                        lng: 4.853680
                    },
                    ne: {
                        lat: 52.402162,
                        lng: 4.978654
                    }
                },
                opts: {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            }
        }
```